# Get i'th element of an array read from an Excel range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have created an array using:

```
Dim PodList() As Variant
Dim i As Long
PodList = Range("A5:A19")

For i = LBound(PodList) To UBound(PodList)
    Range("B4").Value = PodList(i)
Next
```

My line in the loop does not work. I am trying to print/paste the ith element of PodList into cell B4, but I am getting "subscript out of range".

Answer (score 5):

This

```
PodList = Range("A5:A19")
```

returns a two-dimensional array. Reading a range into a Variant always returns a two-dimensional array (except when you're reading a single cell, in which case it's just one value, not an array).

Your 2D array has dimensions (15,1) i.e. 15 rows and 1 column. But by asking for `PodList(i)` i.e. with only one index or subscript, you treated it like a one-dimensional array, which it isn't, hence the "subscript out of range" error.

You want to iterate through the rows of the (one) column, referring to both subscripts of the 2D array, like this:

```
For i = LBound(PodList,1) To UBound(PodList,1)
    Range("B4").Value = PodList(i,1)
Next
```

`LBound(PodList,1)` and `UBound(PodList,1)` tell you the bounds of the first dimension (and will return 1 and 15, respectively).

Comment: For completeness, you could note that the dimension is not explictly required in the `LBound` and `UBound` functions as it will default to 1 so the For Loop used in the OP would increment `i` correctly.

Comment: For such details I refer the OP to the documentation: [`LBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264295%28v=office.14%29.aspx) [`UBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658%28v=office.14%29.aspx)